# Java String format issue

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

I have a problem using the String.format() method.

So I want to create a String with a line feed, for which I use `%n`.

I create the string like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < authorNames.size(); i++) {
  tmpReturnString += authorNames.get(i) + "%n";
}
```

with `authorNames` beeing a ArrayList. 
Next I want to return the formatted String:

`returnResult.setAttributes(0, String.format(tmpReturnString.substring(0, tmpReturnString.length() - 1)))`

`returnResult` is going to be my return.

But here I get a `java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '%'`.

Unfortunatly I have no clue how to fix this issue. Also, non of the other questions helped me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Line feed char is `\n`, try it ;)

Comment: Your `substring` operation removes the `n` from the end.  Why would you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to remove the last new line, but by removing only one character you end up with your string ending with `%`.

Do this instead:

```
String.format(tmpReturnString.substring(0, tmpReturnString.length() - 2))
```

(remove 2 characters instead of just 1)

Or, even better, if you use apache commons:

```
String.format(StringUtils.join(authorNames, "%n"));
```

Comment: Oh dang.. Thank you so much! Was looking at my code for too long not to see that...

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < authorNames.size(); i++) {
  tmpReturnString += authorNames.get(i) + "%n";
}
```

alway return the string with two last character is "%n".
So when you use

```
substring(0, tmpReturnString.length() - 1)
```

Now the last character is '%'.
The '%' is not a valid format specifier.

Detail in here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html